# User specific report in SQL - how to select data based on User Domain name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, report

Due to security requirements, I want to make report where each salesman views only sales data of his Region, and may not view data of other salesmen.

I can imagine that a salesman generating the report can somehow pass in a query his DomainUsername (UserID) based on Windows authentication. Then the query will select only the data based on that UserID. **How to get DomainUsername (UserID) of the user accessing the report in SQL query?**

What are the ways for making user specific reports?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, you should be able to get the domain_username of the user using:

```
SELECT user
```

If you are looking for his ID, may be you can check in the `sysusers` table using the domain_username fetched from the above query.

Comment: I get a result `guest` although I am logged in as a user for Windows domain. Why?

Comment: Can you please try SUSER_NAME()

Comment: `SUSER_NAME()` as well as `SUSER_SNAME()` returns correct information. However I am a bit worried if both of those could be set up by query. `SYSTEM_USER` returns the same information. Which of them is most appropriate in my report?

Comment: Probably `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` should do the work. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/28/sql-server-difference-between-original_login-and-suser_sname/